# How to find the limit of this recursive sequence

Tags: sequence

I want to find the limit of the following recursive sequence when n tends to `∞`:

```
a[1] = 2;
a[n_] := a[n] = 1/2 (a[n - 1] + 1/a[n - 1])
Limit[a[n], n -> Infinity]
```

I don't want to use `RSolve[{a[n + 1] == 1/2 (a[n] + 1/a[n]), a[1] == 2}, a[n], n]` to find its expression and then find the limit, because some nonlinear recursive formulas can't find the general term expression. I want to use a more general method to find the limit of this recursive sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AsymptoticRSolveValue[{{a[n] == (a[n - 1] + 1/a[n - 1])/2}, 
  a[1] == 2}, a[n], n -> Infinity]
```

Answer (score 4):

Convergence occurs when a[n] is equal to a[n-1]. Call the unknown convergent value x, then you are looking for the value x such that x == 1/2 (x + 1/x). This can be found easily:

```
Solve[x == 1/2 (x + 1/x), x]
{{x -> -1}, {x -> 1}}
```

So there are two possible convergent values for your sequence. With a[1]=2, the values will all be positive so you can choose the x->1.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)

```
Clear[a, n]
```

The general solution is

```
sol = RSolve[{a[1] == 2, a[n] == 1/2 (a[n - 1] + 1/a[n - 1])}, a[n], n][[1]] //
   Quiet

(* {a[n] -> Coth[2^(-1 + n) ArcCoth[2]]} *)
```

The limit is then

```
Limit[a[n] /. sol, n -> Infinity]

(* 1 *)
```

**EDIT:** Generalizing the problem

```
Clear[a, n, sol]

sol[x_] = RSolve[{a[1] == 2, a[n] == 1/2 (a[n - 1] + x/a[n - 1])}, a[n], 
    n][[1]] // Quiet

(* {a[n] -> Sqrt[x] Coth[2^(-1 + n) ArcCoth[2/Sqrt[x]]]} *)

lim[x_] = Limit[a[n] /. sol[x], n -> Infinity]

(* ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[x], 
 Sqrt[x] ∈ Reals && ArcCoth[2/Sqrt[x]] > 0] *)
```

For the original problem

```
lim[1]

(* 1 *)
```